# How to use a member variable in a base class function when its size is only known to the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to implement a function in a baseclass that uses members of its derived classes. So with each DerivedClass, I would have a member of a different value.
Here's an example. The `BaseClass` has member function `Foo()` which uses variable `arrStr`. This content of this NUL terminated char array however is only to be found in a derived class.
How can I make `BaseClass` "know" the variable `arrStr` without knowing its size? Is that even possible?

```
    class BaseClass
    {
    public:
        BaseClass();
        ~BaseClass();

    protected:

    void Foo()
    {
     prtinf("%s\n", arrStr);
    };

    };

    class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
        {
        public:
            DerivedClass();
            ~DerivedClass();

            protected:

            char arrStr[] = "FooString!";
     };
```

Comment: A base class knowing details of a derived one is a design problem. But you could declare and use virtual functions in the base class, and implement them in the derived one. There isn't enough information to figure out what problem you're really trying to solve though.

Comment: Thanks! However, with the derived class I wanted to eliminate overhead that I had since every derived class has the same implementation of the `Foo` function.

Comment: Make `Foo()` call (a) private virtual function(s) that is (are) implemented in the derived classes.

Comment: Why don't you just store a pointer or reference in the baseclass? How much is the overhead that you measured?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you, of course. This is what I was looking for. I didnt measure the overhead, probably the compiler would have optimized this anyway. I just didnt want three implementations fo the same function.

Comment: Given the additional information, the solution may be to let the `Foo()` function be part of a helper class instead. Inheritance isn't always the answer.

Comment: If every derived class had exactly the same implementation of `Foo`, including the reference to a `arrStr` member, then maybe the `arrStr` member belongs in the base class too?

Answer (score 2):

Add (pure) virtual access functions in your base class which you implement in the derived class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BaseClass
{
protected:
    void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << GetString() << std::endl;
    }

private:    
    virtual std::string GetString() const = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
private:
    virtual std::string GetString() const override
    {
        return "FooString!";
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/83ume)

Comment: `GetString()` could and probably should be private. But +1 anyway.

Comment: ...and it should probably be `const`, too.

Comment: Agree on both comments. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make BaseClass "know" the variable arrStr without knowing its size? Is that even possible?

You insert it as a parameter when calling Foo:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void Process() = 0;
protected:
    void Foo(char* str) // <-- value inserted here as parameter
    {
        prtinf("%s\n", arrStr);
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void Process() override
    {
        Foo(arrStr); // call in derived class, with derived value
    }
protected:
    char arrStr[] = "FooString!";
};
```

Client code:

```
BaseClass * b = new DerivedClass;
b->Process(); // call Foo(arrStr) internally
```